# Ошибка десериализации XML при неявном приведении типов

Tags: c#, xml, сериализация, cast, deserialize

Помогите найти причину ошибки.

Есть класс точки в который включено неявное приведение в другие типы точек (один из математической библиотеки, два других из AutoCAD)

```
  public class Point : ICloneable
    {
        public string Id;
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public double X { get; set; }
        public double Y { get; set; }
        public double Z { get; set; }
    
        public Point()
        {
            Id = string.Empty;
            Name = string.Empty;
            X = 0;
            Y = 0;
            Z = 0;
        }
    
        public Point(double X, double Y, double Z)
        {
            Id = string.Empty;
            Name = string.Empty;
            this.X = X;
            this.Y = Y;
            this.Z = Z;
        }
    
    
        public static implicit operator Point3d(Point point)
        {
            return new Point3d(point.X, point.Y, point.Z);
        }
        public static implicit operator PolylineVertex3d(Point point)
        {
            return new PolylineVertex3d(point);
        }
        public static implicit operator MathPoint(Point point)
        {
            return new MathPoint(point.X, point.Y, point.Z);
        }
    
        public object Clone()
        {
            return MemberwiseClone();
        }
    }
```

Есть класс в котором происходит собственно сериализация/десериализация.

```
public class Section
{
    public Section()
    {
        Wells = new List<Well>();
    }
    public Section(List<Well> Wells)
    {
        this.Wells = Wells;
    }
    public List<Well> Wells { get; set; }
    public string HorizontalScale { get; set; }
    public string VerticalScale { get; set; }

    public static Section LoadSection(string path)
    {
        try
        {
            using (StreamReader fs = new StreamReader(path, Encoding.GetEncoding(1251)))
            {
                XmlSerializer xmlSerializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Section));



                xmlSerializer.UnknownElement += (sender, e) =>
                {
                    var sec = (Well)e.ObjectBeingDeserialized;

                    if (e.Element.Name == "WellHeight")
                    {
                        sec.WellHeadPoint.Z = double.Parse(e.Element.InnerText);
                    }
                };




             return (Section)xmlSerializer.Deserialize(fs);
            }
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            return new Section();
        }
    }

    public void SaveSection(string path)
    {
        using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Create))
        {
            using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(fs, Encoding.GetEncoding(1251)))
            {

                XmlSerializer xmlSerializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Section));
                xmlSerializer.Serialize(writer, this);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Section содержит Well, Well содержит Point.

При попытке десериализовать объект пока в классе Point есть неявное приведение выбрасывается ошибка "невозможно создать временный класс (результат=1). CS0012 тип *тип* определен в сборке ссылка на которую отсутствует".
При этом все ссылки есть и в остальной части программы работают.

Полазив по интернету не нашел ничего по теме, чего-то точно не вижу, тыканье носом приветствуется.

Comment: У `XmlSerializer` есть конструктор, принимающий массив `extraTypes`. Попробуйте указать эти дополнительные типы.

Comment: Получилось, спасибо большое.

Comment: Оформите ответ. Напишите, как именно сделали. И потом примите его.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    public static Section LoadSection(string path)
    {
        try
        {
            using (StreamReader fs = new StreamReader(path, Encoding.GetEncoding(1251)))
            {
                XmlSerializer xmlSerializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Section),new Type[] {typeof(MathPoint), typeof(Point3d), typeof(PolylineVertex3d)});



                xmlSerializer.UnknownElement += (sender, e) =>
                {
                    var sec = (Well)e.ObjectBeingDeserialized;

                    if (e.Element.Name == "WellHeight")
                    {
                        sec.WellHeadPoint.Z = double.Parse(e.Element.InnerText);
                    }
                };




             return (Section)xmlSerializer.Deserialize(fs);
            }
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            return new Section();
        }
    }
```

Вот так просто всё и решается, ещё раз спасибо Alexander Petrov